# Cell height is not increasing depend on the label text in tableview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, label, tableview

I need to change cell height depend on the message label text

[Cell.Xib Design img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGDTL.png)

for message label i have given constraints

```
 trailing = leading = top = 10, height => 30 (greater then or equal to height)
```

and line count = 0

now label is increasing but cell is not increasing why?

o/p

[o/p img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh6rQ.png)

code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return msgArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageDetailsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageDetailsTableViewCell
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    cell.msgLabel.text = msgArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.picImageview.image = UIImage(named: "icon12")
    
    return cell
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100//UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

if i give `heightForRowAt = UITableView.automaticDimension` then nothing comes, if i fixed its height to 100 then cell is not increasing, why? please do help

Comment: Please see this https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/, I hope it will help.

Comment: check you cell lblheight will not be fixed.

Comment: you need to fix bottomlayout constraint of your label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to follow the below steps.

**Step1:** Set the constraint of your label as leading, trailing, top and bottom. Set bottom constraint to greater than equal to.

[image]

**Step 2:** Set label's number of lines to 0.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

**Step 3:** In ViewDidLoad Function

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go simple with two number of steps:

**1. heightForRowAt Method:**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableView.automaticDimension
   }
```

**2. UILabel Property**

```
   yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // or you can set numberOfLines from storyBoard.
```